# What is the best point estimator from the following 3, using the MSE?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I have 3 point estimators and their MSEs were calculated:

[image]

The best one is supposed to be the one with the lowest MSE. The solutions say it's the 2nd one. The values of $\sigma^2$ and $\mu$ aren't given. This is more of a calculus question than a statistics question. Why is $\frac{\sigma^2}{3}$ smaller than $\frac{8\sigma^2}{9}+\frac{\mu^2}{9}$?

Comment: By the way, out of curiosity, what is MSE?

Comment: @lcv - probably *mean square error*, equal to variance plus square of the bias of the estimator

Comment: @thanks got it. I knew it was something in estimation theory. But I forgot

Answer (score 1):

Well I dont have a reputation of 50 yet so I cant comment, but also I don't have an answer, but here are my thoughts:

I dont think this is a calculus problem as more of a find a substitution thing...

So we know that $\mu=\sigma^2-E(Y^2)$, therefore,

MSE($\hat\theta_3$) = 8$\sigma^2/9+\mu^2/9$

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ = 8$\sigma^2/9 + \sigma^2/9 - E(Y^2)/9$

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ =$\sigma^2 - E(Y^2)/9$

But E($Y^2$) = $\frac{1}{n}\Sigma y^2_i$

So now we have

=$\sigma^2 - E(Y^2)/9$ = $\sigma^2 -\frac{1}{9n}\Sigma y^2_i$

But $\frac{1}{n}\Sigma y^2_i$ is the second moment estimator as each moment estimator is given by $E(Y^k)=\frac{1}{n}\Sigma y^k_i$ for the kth moment.

So since you already have the second moment you can plug that in:

= $\sigma^2 -\frac{1}{9n}\Sigma y^2_i$ = $\sigma^2 - \frac{1}{27}\sigma^2$

But this is bigger that MSE($\hat\sigma_2$) so idk, maybe these steps I took might help you

Maybe post the full problem?

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma^2$ and $\mu^2$ are positive or at least non negative and $0 < \frac13 < \frac89$ and $0 < \frac19$

so

$$\frac{1}{3}\sigma^2 \le \frac{8}{9}\sigma^2 \le \frac{8}{9}\sigma^2+\frac{1}{9}\mu^2$$

with the first inequality being strict if $\sigma^2 > 0$